# What does this PHP function return?

Tags: php, function, return-value, associativity

public function add($child){
        return $this->children[]=$child;
    }

Btw, this is an excerpt from PHP in Action by Dagfinn Reiersol. According to the book, this returns $child, but shouldn't it return true in case of successful assignment and false otherwise?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It returns `$child`. This is because `$child` is first added to the array `$this->children[]`. Then, the result of this assignment is returned.

Essentially, it is shorthand for:

```
public function add($child){
    $this->children[]=$child;
    return $child;
}
```

This type of shortcut works because, in PHP, assignment is "right-associative": http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

This means that `$a = ($b = 3)` is actually evaluated from right-to-left, with `3` being stored in `$b` *and then* `$a`. Also, here is a note on the page I provided a link to:

> Although = has a lower precedence than
>   most other operators, PHP will still
>   allow expressions similar to the
>   following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in which
>   case the return value of `foo()` is put
>   into `$a`.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Comment: Hm.. Ok.. I haven't much time right now but I'll give it a little more thought and then come back and mark it as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks, I posted what the expression would look like without using the shortcut.

Comment: Nice explanation, @SimpleCoder. But yikes -- the length of explanation required is a perfect illustration of why that sort of shorthand is a BAD IDEA in real-life code. Hope the author of PHP in Action was using it as a case-study of how not to write maintainable code.

Comment: @Ben Dunlap; Thanks. I 100% agree, it is VERY easy to mistake `=` for `==` in those situations. That's how nasty errors and mistakes creep in.

Answer (score 1):

It does return child, because an assignment just returns whatever was assigned.

Whether or not it should return true on success is not a rule, so if it was *documented* to return child, it is correct.